# Unable to run the demo code of classification/Object Deection on Coral Docs

Tags: gstreamer, tpu, google-coral

When I run the following demo code on my Coral,

```
edgetpu_detect \
--source /dev/video1:YUY2:800x600:24/1  \
--model ${DEMO_FILES}/ssd_mobilenet_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite
```

I am getting the following error:

v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=800,height=600,framerate=24/1 ! glupload ! tee name=t
t. ! queue ! glsvgoverlaysink name=glsink
t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! glfilterbin filter=glbox ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=320,height=320 ! appsink name=appsink emit-signals=True max-buffers=1 drop=True sync=False
Error: gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1): gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Could someone please help me out with this?

I am trying to run the demo ode on Google Coral Docs, but no luck. First I thought it is the problem with my camera, but it is not the case as I can see the feed using

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! autovideosink
```